# Android permission to Show app icon badges

Tags: android

How do we get permission to `Show app icon badges` on android phones so that the switch in the settings comes on.  Please see the image

The location for this page is `settings->Apps->Manage apps->Your app->Notifications` and switch on the `Show app icon badges` on `Redmi Note 5`.  But I am looking for solution for all devices.

Shortcut badger seems to have issues with Google Play Store terms and conditions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Open Notification Settings

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
                intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: not open, get permission automatically, can't ask thousands of users to go manually and set this setting...

Comment: since this is the only way now I mark it as an anser